# How Skip VR entry Screens with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

I know how to disable the tutorial of Daydream screen on Daydream app / Developer Options and checking Skip VR Entry Screens.

But, I need it. The problem with screen is because the entry screen is shown at the beginning of the app. I need this screen on my second scene!

If you have a way to disable it by code could you show it?

Comment: I don't think you can rearrange the order of the screens(Making the Unity Splash screen come second, you can remove the splash screen completely if you have pro or plus I believe).

Comment: If you have Unity PRO you can disable the screen at the beginning. Later you can just show something that looks like this Unity screen using animation.

Comment: It's not Unity Splash Screen. It's the Daydream VR Splash Screen and controller wake-up.  

http://30icsk46wnxx3t69qb2h5nfj.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/placing_method.png

http://30icsk46wnxx3t69qb2h5nfj.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/aim_forward.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

It's needed disable the NFC option on mobile settings.